# GCP FCM : acknowledgment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does GCP's FCM send any acknowledgement that the user has read the notification to the calling service? Or can it be configured to do so? Can you please provide any documentation regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

No, Firebase Cloud Messaging does not track whether the user has read a notification.

If your use-case needs read confirmation, you'll have to implement a "Mark as read" UI element in the notification yourself, as you may have seen in WhatsApp, Messages, and/or other apps.